# How to get sum of rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I need to get total of each row, but i can't take the alias name for the row as it gives error. How to get sum() for the row in the below statement.

```
select sum(Amount) as [Amount total],
       sum(balance) as [Balance Total],
       sum(Remaining) as [Remaining Total]
from MyTable
```

I want to do something like

```
select sum(Amount) as [Amount total],
       sum(balance) as [Balance Total],
       sum(Remaining) as [Remaining Total],
       [Amount total]+[Balance Total]+[Remaining Total] as Total
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeat the expression, use a subquery, or use a CTE.  Here is the first choice:

```
select sum(Amount) as [Amount total],
       sum(balance) as [Balance Total],
       sum(Remaining) as [Remaining Total],
       (sum(Amount) + sum(balance) + sum(Remaining)) as Total
from MyTable;
```

Column aliases are not recognized at the same level where they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS [Amount total], 
       SUM(balance) AS [Balance Total], 
       SUM(Remaining) AS [Remaining Total], 
       SUM(Amount + balance + Remaining) AS Total
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to SUM the SUMS, just SUM the columns that they are SUMming, and you will get the total sum:

```
select sum(Amount) as [Amount total],sum(balance)[Balance Total]
,sum(Remaining)[Remaining Total],SUM(Amount+Balance+Remaining) as Total
    from MyTable
```